# Cannot access res folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, inputstream

I have a Java programming problem I would like some help on!

I have my class files in a separate package (not default package). I am trying to access a file from my res folder. I have added it as a class folder (using properties --> libraries --> add class folder) In my class I have the following code:

```
InputStream IS = getClass().getResourceAsStream("mytextfile.txt");
```

However it doesn't work, I have all the proper imports and everything but I just can't get it to work... (gives null pointer exception when I try to use the IS)

I think it has something to do with using a separate package, because I have another program that uses the default package and it works fine...

I want a way where I can access the file both when I'm using Eclipse and when I have it exported as a .jar.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: I have tried using /res/mytextfile.txt but that doesn't work either...

Comment: Which package are the class and the resource in? The code you have now assumes they are in the same package. If they are not, use the full package path `getResourceAsStream("/a/b/c/mytextfile.txt")`.

Comment: oh so they have to be in the same package? What if my res folder is an added class folder? and not part of the package?

Comment: And what is the class folder you added? If you added `res`, then `res` is not the package name anymore. Best practice layout is `src/main/resources/res/mytextfile.txt` (with "resources" the class folder).

Comment: @user2804925 No they don't HAVE to be in the same package, it's just `getClass().getResource` will attempt to do a relative lookup unless you supply a `/` at the start of the path...

Comment: @Thilo If I do scr/main/resources/res/mytextfile.txt will it work for a .jar file where everything is in the same directory?

Comment: Well, you have to build your jar file properly. In the jar, the path must be "res/mytextfile.txt".

Comment: @Thilo How do I set up eclipse to create that folder inside the jar file? Because the jar files I've created the files just end up placed all in the same directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getClass().getResource` will look for the named resource relative to the location that the class exists.

So if the class exists in the package `foo.bar`, `getResource` will look in `foo/bar/mytextfile.txt` (prefixing the classes, classloader's class path context...)

Instead, try using a relative path, such as

```
InputStream IS = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mytextfile.txt");
```

or

```
InputStream IS = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/mytextfile.txt");
```

Assuming that the resource directory is called `res` and exists under the default package

Comment: the /mytextfile.txt worked! Dumb mistake by me, thanks for your help! 1 more question, is it safe to assume the / makes it go up 1 directory before searching for the file?

Comment: No, the / does not make it up go 1. It means "start at the top". If `/mytextfile.txt` works, then that file is not in any package.

Comment: No.  It's safe to assume that it starts at the top of the class path context (confused now). So if you had your resources in `{default package}/resources/files` for example and your class was in `foo.bar`, you would need to use the `/resources/files` path to find it.

Comment: @Thilo Technically, it's in the "default package", but that's a nit pick :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I refuse the acknowledge the existence (or right to existence) of the so-called "default package". ;-) Never use it.