# Java: Loading BufferedImage from res Folder

Tags: java, classpath, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Im trying to load an image from my res folder which **is already part of the Java BuildPath**. Sadly it seems I am no able to find the image neither with relative nor with an absolute path to the file.
Im always getting this error message:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
 at schneider.twodgame.BufferedImageLoader.loadImage(BufferedImageLoader.java:14)
 at schneider.twodgame.Game.init(Game.java:64)
 at schneider.twodgame.Game.run(Game.java:99)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And here is a part of the code:

```
public class BufferedImageLoader {

private BufferedImage image;

public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(getClass());
    image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
    return image;
    }
}
```

This is the method I am trying to load the image with. The method is part of my Main Class:

```
public void init() {
    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();

    try {
        spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/res/sprite_sheet.png");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107669/cannot-access-res-folder).

```
spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/sprite_sheet.png");
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently looking in your .class file folder or .jar file at the location of your class files in:

```
[root folder of class files]/res/sprite_sheet.png
```

Maybe it should be looking in:

```
[root folder of class files]/schneider/twodgame/res/sprite_sheet.png
```

In that case you should remove the leading slash (`/`).